# C++ std::string to char for using with OpenGL LoadBMP

Tags: c++, string, opengl, char

I've got an string array

```
string name[1000];
```

and with

```
int counter;
counter = 0;

while(FindNextFile(fHandle, &wf))
{

 ... //some more code which is checking if its a folder

string theName = wf.cFileName;
if(theName.find(".bmp") != std::string::npos)
{
    name[counter] = theName;
    counter++;
}
}
```

I am adding each .bmp file to my name array.

Using [NeHe's Tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06) I'm adding Textures to my Qubes, which is working very well.

Now my customized code looks like this:

```
int n; string imageFileString[1000]; char *imageFile[1000];
for(n=0; n<1000; n++)
{
    imageFileString[n] = name[n];
    imageFile[n] = new char[imageFileString[n].length()];
    strcpy(imageFile[n], imageFileString[n].c_str());

    if(TextureImage[n] = loadBMP(imageFile[n]))
    {
        ... // Some more Functions to set textures
    }
}
```

Everything is working well, only that my BMP Files arent loaded.

If I add

```
name[0] = "pic1.bmp";
name[1] = "pic2.bmp";
name[2] = "pic2.bmp";
name[3] = "pic2.bmp";
```

before setting the `int n; string imageFileString...`, so for the `for(...)` loop my Pictures are loaded without changing anything else. My first opinion was that the name array has no entrys, but I created a Log file with the output

```
name[0] << endl << name[1] << endl << name[2] ...
```

and in my Log file were the same names

```
pic1.bmp
pic2.bmp
pic3.bmp
```

so I think there is some other error adding the cFileName to my array.

Can anyone help me please? I dont know how to fix this, i mean I've no idea what is wrong...

Comment: Instead of string name[1000] why dont you use std::vector<std::string> names;. And use names.push_back(theName);.

Answer (score 4):

```
imageFile[n] = new char[imageFileString[n].length()];
```

You're not accounting for the null-terminator. Add one to the length:

```
imageFile[n] = new char[imageFileString[n].length() + 1];
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an answer, but it would be too hard to post in a comment.

Why are you doing all this?

```
int n; string imageFileString[1000]; char *imageFile[1000];
for(n=0; n<1000; n++)
{
    imageFileString[n] = name[n];
    imageFile[n] = new char[imageFileString[n].length()];
    strcpy(imageFile[n], imageFileString[n].c_str());

    if(TextureImage[n] = loadBMP(imageFile[n]))
    {
        ... // Some more Functions to set textures
    }
}
```

When you could just do this?

```
int n;
for(n=0; n<1000; n++)
{
    if(TextureImage[n] = loadBMP(name[n].c_str()))
    {
        ... // Some more Functions to set textures
    }
}
```

Comment: converting const char* in char* is not possible, thats the error.

Comment: @ahmet2106 Then fix loadBMP.  It should accept a const char* instead of a char*

Comment: @PigBen +1 nice :) Thank you, but this doesnt fix my error :D

Comment: @ahmet2106 I'm pretty sure const_cast would be your friend in that situation.

Comment: @PigBen I hadnt realized, for whatever reason, that loadBMP was his own function.

Comment: @ahmet2106 I realize that, that's why I said it wasn't an answer and I made it community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said everything works fine when you do `name[0] = "pic1.bmp"` etc, you need to print out/debug `string theName = wf.cFileName`; I would guess it is a pathing issue. wf.cFileName is probably returning a file path you aren't expecting.

For example I bet it's returning something like `\MyData\Bitmaps\pic1.bmp` where you are only expecting `pic1.bmp`

**Update**

Given all the other wonderful changes, you can also shorten it even further and do this

```
int counter = 0;

while (FindNextFile(fHandle, &wf))
{
    if (strstr(wf.cFileName, ".bmp") != 0)
    {
          if(TextureImage[counter] = loadBMP(wf.cFileName)
          {
             ... // Some more Functions to set textures
             counter++
          }
    }
}
```

There isn't any reason to allocate more memory just to check if a string (".bmp") is present. Also note I don't update the counter unless the load succeeds.

You really should switch TextureImage to a `std::vector` then you wouldnt have to do any counting. Check to see if you pass wf.cFileName directly to your loadBMP if things work. And I do realize that this could present in an overflow due to `TextureImage[]` and counter which is why I suggest switching to `std::vector`. We don't see how he allocates `TextureImage[]`, if it's like everything else it was with a magic number of 1000.

Also keep in mind that .cFileName is defined as TCHAR[] which can hold unicode values.

Comment: no, as i said, if im creating a log file with name[0], there is the pic1.bmp in my log file. So I dont think that there is a problem with the path.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the Problem myself,

Update, fixed version (WinMain):

```
void ScanTheDirectory()
{
    // this function is scanning the directory and is adding
    // each bmp file to the string array "name"
}

int initGL()
{
    // this function calls the loadTextures() function
}

int loadTextures()
{
    // this function is loading all files of the string array "name"
    // converts them to a const char * and is adding them to the "textures" GLuint (array)
}

int WINAPI WinMain()
{
    // this function is the main window which is showing the
    // qubes (GL_QUBES)

    ScanTheDirectory();
    initGL();
}
```

The Problem was in WinMain(), because it looked like this:

```
initGL();
ScanTheDirectory();
```

If it is first calling the initGL(), so it is creating the Textures, and because the name array is empty, there are no Textures added to my Textures array.

After changing this to

```
ScanTheDirectory();
initGL();
```

Now it is first calling the ScanTheDirectory() void and so my name array is filled with names of BMP Image Files.
Now it can call the initGL and this is creating the Textures out of my Images.

Thanks for the Help, now my Code is looking a little bit clearer :D

Ahmet

Comment: That doesn't make much sense given the code you've presented. Would you mind updating this with your modified code so that others may learn based on this.

Comment: @Andrew, now I changed a bit my answer, this is a part of the code with description. More helpful I think.

Comment: I appreciate it, thank you. Now others will see that ordering matters.